# sql broker route tcp test to same server

Tags: sql-server, message-queue, routes, service-broker, endpoint

For testing purposes, I placed two databases on the same server, I want to send queued messages between databases via TCP (not GUID.) Would I still need an endpoint since its all on 1 server? Also do I use tcp://127.0.0.1:PORT or tcp://IP:port?

Lastly is the **ReceivingService** in the route the service on the target database **or** the service on the initiating database? Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE ROUTE Route_to_Target_Database_On_Same_Server
WITH
BROKER_INSTANCE = '111F27B6-1211-10E1-1711-B1D19113121111',
SERVICE_NAME = 'ReceivingService',
ADDRESS = 'TCP://127.0.0.1:2044'


CREATE ENDPOINT BrokerEndpoint
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 2044 )
FOR SERVICE_BROKER (
ENCRYPTION = DISABLED);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Both work. Just have to becarefull of firewalls/closed ports and permissions are correct on both machines. No need for endpoints if on same server, but if its remote then endpoints are a must (with correct user permissions on both)